# Why is this / directory not the same as what I set it to be?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, root, disk

I'm a newbie in Ubuntu and encountered some problems with the storage. I'm dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 10. I partitioned my hard disk so / directory had 20 GB, /home directory had 5 GB, and swap area had 2 GB.

I was using the "sudo apt upgrade" command, and it told me that my disk was running out of space. After checking the Disk Usage Manager, I found that my root directory somehow changed to a 3.1 GB directory.
[here's the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AITya.png) (The screenshot was taken after I rebooted and lost all the previous data, so it doesn't show as full now.)

Can anyone explain this to me please? Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:** **I deleted the partition I created for Ubuntu and tried to reinstall it. I found that BEFORE I WENT THROUGH ALL THE INSTALL PROCESS, the 3.1 GB space already existed in the device manager.**

**UPDATE 2: After the re-installation, I can still see the 3.1 GB directory AND the root directory I created. I clicked in both of them and saw [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtD0j.png)**. The one on the left it's the 20 GB real root directory and on the right it's the 3.1 GB one, for some reason labeled /. Why are they both storing /usr and everything else, but don't really have the same contents (cuz size is different)? How can I save stuff (like when I use the upgrade command) to the 20 GB instead of the 3.1 GB?

Sorry for the verbose updates and thanks again to all who have helped!

Comment: Did you boot to a live USB?

Comment: you actually mounted your os on 5 gb partition rather 20 gb, you need to reinstall the os and this time making the 20 gb partition as your root(/) mount point.

Comment: @muru I booted from a live USB and installed it on my PC.

Comment: @AkhilVarma Then why does the 3.1G one show as a separate device than the 5G Volume? Also I'm wondering if a successfully installed os has an extra directory  like mine? :(

Comment: it appears that you made the partitions but didn't tell the installer to use the partitions. so it used the remaining free space 3.1GB for your entire system.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.